# How can i take an SVG image of a circle and put it at the bottom of the webpage, in a way that you can only see the top half all the time

Tags: html, css

I want to make the circle image spin so you only see the top half as it spins and the user cant scroll down to see the other half, while not adding scroll bars due to scale increase of the image or width/height.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLcMl.png)
can this be done with CSS or java?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be pretty easily accomplished by creating an absolutely positioned overflow-hidden wrapper, and adding a spin animation to an element inside the wrapper.

```css
.spinner {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  overflow: hidden;

  height: calc(50vw / 2);
}

.spinner img {
  animation: spin 5s linear infinite;

  width: 50vw;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

@keyframes spin {
    from {transform:rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the part I was missing from my code was the overflow: hidden attribute, I appreciate the help.